# affdex.cpp:9:31: fatal error: pybind11/pybind11.h: No such file or directory #include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

Tags: python, c++, linux, centos, pybind11

I can import pybind11 in Python and it is in the include path. However, I get the following error following the instructions [here](https://github.com/ahamino/affdex-sdk-py):

```
(venv)[jalal@ivcgpu1 affdex-sdk-py]$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  4 2017, 00:39:18) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pybind11
>>> pybind11.get_include()
'/home/grad3/jalal/venv/include/site/python2.7'
>>> pybind11.get_include(True)
'/home/grad3/jalal/venv/include/site/python2.7'
>>> quit()
(venv)[jalal@ivcgpu1 affdex-sdk-py]$ c++ -O3 -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC -Wl,--no-as-needed -I$AFFDEX_SDK_HOME/include -I$HOME/venv/include/site/python2.7 `python-config --cflags --ldflags --libs` -Wl,--no-as-needed -laffdex-native -L$AFFDEX_SDK_HOME/lib affdex.cpp -o affdex.so
affdex.cpp:9:31: fatal error: pybind11/pybind11.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
                               ^
compilation terminated.
(venv)[jalal@ivcgpu1 affdex-sdk-py]$
```

How can I fix this error?

UPDATE:

```
(venv)[jalal@ivcgpu1 affdex-sdk-py]$ echo $HOME
/home/grad3/jalal
(venv)[jalal@ivcgpu1 affdex-sdk-py]$ echo $HOME/venv/include/site/python2.7
/home/grad3/jalal/venv/include/site/python2.7
```

Comment: Did you set the right path? `$HOME` equals to `/home/grad3`, and `$HOME/venv/include/site/python2.7` equals to `/home/grad3/venv/include/site/python2.7`. It seems you're missing something?

Comment: @Sraw yes please see the updates

Answer (score 0):

I saw the following error message when trying to install `scipy` for `pypy`:

```
  scipy/fft/_pocketfft/pypocketfft.cxx:15:31: fatal error: pybind11/pybind11.h: No such file or directory
   #include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
                                 ^
  compilation terminated.
  scipy/fft/_pocketfft/pypocketfft.cxx:15:31: fatal error: pybind11/pybind11.h: No such file or directory
   #include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
```

The fix was:

```
$ python -m pip install pybind11
```

Comment: I also had to install `$ sudo apt-get install pypy-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the include dir in your compile command ?

like `-I/[pathToPython]/Lib/site-packages/pybind11/include`